# Trying to hang a heavy mirror and dry wall anchors won’t go all the way in

Tags: drywall, hanging, mirror

I’m trying to hang a heavy mirror (about 17 pounds) and it came with a few drywall anchors. The problem is we just drilled the first hole, and the anchor won’t go all the way in because there is what seems like metal blocking it (so can’t drill any further)

Am I not able to hang my mirror here?

Or is there any other way to hang it?

Comment: Metal behind drywall is one of three things.  Metal studs(not bad), metal pipe(bad), metal plate protecting electrical wires(also bad).  Need to find which it is.

Comment: Could also be metal plate protecting drain pipe or protecting water supply pipe.

Comment: Depending where you are , electric may be in steel conduit.

Answer (score 1):

I have several large mirrors in my home several over 6’ wide. All are hung with a French cleat. This method utilizes interlocking 45-degree-angle slopes to hold my mirrors in place. One side is glued to the mirror the other has glue but also screwed to the wall at the studs.  The design has been a go-to method for mounting cabinets, hanging heavy mirrors and securing large-format artwork for hundreds of years. There are many variations of this, your favorite box store probably has several varieties.